# advisability of taskkill to close an application

Tags: backup, process, scheduled-task, corruption

Before running backups on the data from an application I need to close it cleanly without risking an improper shutdown and data corruption in a Paradox Database.

How likely is that, if I use taskkill and force the process to close in a batch file? 
That is what I am planning but I wonder if I might face other problems as a result.

No one can ever seem to remember to shut the program down normally.

Comment: Killing a task is the exact opposite of closing it down cleanly..

Comment: Any suggestions on how to script a clean  closing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What corrupts databases are uncommited writes. I don't know how prone Paradox is to that kind of thing, but the sort of ungraceful shutdown taskkill does makes it much more likely to happen. If the application hasn't done anything in a while chances are good you'll get away with it, but you're GOING to hit corruption at some point.

Comment: thanks for that. I am getting corruption now when the application is left open indefinitely with unsaved images which it catalogs.